# Howto: Taking photos in windows mobile without CameraCaptureDialog?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, camera, sharpdevelop

I want to create a windows mobile app (windows mobile 5.0 and above, using CompactFramework [in SharpDevelop]) to capture photos automatically, without user involvement (like it would be with CameraCaptureDialog). After going through google searches I found out a solution that should work (http://blogs.msdn.com/marcpe/archive/2006/03/03/542941.aspx)[1](http://blogs.msdn.com/marcpe/archive/2006/03/03/542941.aspx) but I cannot compile the source (I guess that is because I use sharpdevelop not MS Visual Studio).

- Are there any other options available?
- Maybe there is a binary version of that CameraCapture Library somewhere so I can use it without compiling on my own?
- Anyone willing to compile the one I linked above and post it somewhere to make binary version available [I tried searching for such in google, but with no success]

Answer (score 1):

The CameraCaptureDialog is part of the Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Forms assembly, which chips in ROM on WinMo 5.0 and later devices.  The device SDKs also whip with copies of these assemblies so the apps can build (for example mine is on my PC at C:\Program Files\Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK R2\Managed Libraries).  I would assume you should be able to manually add a reference to that assembly in SharpDevelop.